# Calling typescript component function to scss file (Angular)

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to call this auto detect function from my component.ts file to my .scss file and I don't know how to or if it is even possible.

`example.component.scss`

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: getScreenHeight;   <--- ERROR
  width:  getScreenWidth;    <--- ERROR
}
```

`example.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class exampleComponent implements OnInit {
  public getScreenWidth: any;
  public getScreenHeight: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.getScreenHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onWindowResize() {
    this.getScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.getScreenHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }
}
```

For reference I am using this functionality [detection](https://www.positronx.io/angular-detect-width-and-height-of-screen-tutorial/)

Tried to call in html and in the .scss. Nothing has worked and have not found similar problems/questions

Answer (score 0):

CSS is not that dynamic so approaching it from the SCSS file will give you problems, instead use inline styles for such problems.

```
<div class="content" [ngStyle]="{ height: getScreenHeight width: getScreenWidth }">
    <!--content inside here-->
</div>
```